# Map of enum types in C++

Tags: c++, enums

Is it possible to memorise a type into a variable?.

The problem:

I have [Enum1, Enum2, Enum3...] and [Enum_x1, Enum_x2, ...], The type Enum1 can be casted only to Enum_x1.

Until now I found only std::is_same::value so, if I want to check if the type can be casted to other type I need to do a lot of `if(std::is_same<x, Enum1>) then...`

Thus I would need a map of types.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more (a code sample would be great) what exactly you want to achieve please?

Comment: How are `Enum1` and `Enum_x1` related?

Comment: It would be a lot of code, I just need to check some rules when I cast an enum to another

Comment: Enum1 and Enum_x1 are related only by the fact that the members have the same values and the number of the members are the same in both enums